# Formatting axis labels using ChartsJS

Tags: chart.js

I am playing with chartsJS and I want to do 2 formatting things. each formatting thing works individually but dont work when i do them together.

Format 1: set the Y axis to start at 0. I did this by the following:

```
options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Number of faults'
    },
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0
        }
      }]
    },
```

Format 2: add in an axis label:

```
options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'probability'
      }
    }]
  }     
}
```

But when I try to do both at the same time it doesn't work:

```
options: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Number of faults'
  },
  responsive: false,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      labelString: 'probability'
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0
      }
    }]
  },
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add a comma behind this line `labelString: 'probability'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to place the `labelstring` in the `scaleLabel` property again for your combined config, if you put it like this it should work:

```
options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Number of faults'
    },
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'probability'
            },
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                min: 0
            }
        }]
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem. i appreciate the help